# how to define constructor in intent

Tags: android

i want to send data another activity with constructor without putextras

//Recever Activity

```
 public Activity_Searching(int selected, String query)
    {
        this.Selected = selected;
        this.Query = query;
    }
```

//Sender Activity

```
 Activity_Searching searching = new Activity_Searching(Selected, v.getText().toString());
    startActivity(new Intent(context, searching.getClass()));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Question seems to be quite unclear. You might want to refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not possible because with Intent you can call a activity not object.

Answer (score 1):

because you are starting a activity, the second parameter should be a `Class<? extends Activity>`

if you not want to use `putExtra`, to add a method `Intent getNewIntentWithParam(Context cxt, Class activityClass, int selected, String query)` is a simple way. if you need more common function to add data to Intent'sExtra, to use java reflect.